# Oracle cursor query return multiple record sets how to fetch in zend or php?

Tags: php, oracle, zend-framework

I have a problem to fetch record sets from following oralce select query:

```
SELECT ap.PROFILE_FIRST_NAME AS "profileFirstName",
        CURSOR (
                   SELECT ae.EMAIL_ADDRESS AS "emailAddress",
                          ae.EMAIL_ADDRESS_IS_PRIMARY AS "emailAddressIsPrimary"
                      FROM APP_EMAIL_ADDRESS ae
                   WHERE ae.LOGIN_INFO_ID = ap.LOGIN_INFO_ID
               ) as "emails",
        CURSOR(
                 select co.CONTACT_NUMBER AS "contactNumber" 
                 FROM APP_CONTACT co where co.LOGIN_INFO_ID = ap.LOGIN_INFO_ID
               ) as "contacts"   

        FROM APP_PROFILE ap
```

When I execute this query in Toad it returns records as expected.
Each user have multiple email, and contact numbers. But when I execute this query in Zend like

```
    $DB = Zend_Registry::get("DB");
    $result = $DB->fetchAll($query);
```

$result have following values:

```
Array
(
 [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [profileFirstName] => 
        [emails] => Resource id #139
        [contacts] => Resource id #140
    )

 [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [profileFirstName] => Zain
        [emails] => Resource id #141
        [contacts] => Resource id #142
    )
 )
```

As I expect emails should be 2D array to contain emails of each user same as contacts should contain contacts array. But the problem is Resource id #. How can I get those values from Resource Id #.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution I have found for this problem.

```
$DB = Zend_Registry::get("DB");
$con = $DB->getConnection();
$stmt = oci_parse($con, $query); // $query can be Resource #id 
oci_execute($stmt);
while ($row = oci_fetch_object($stmt))
```